# ¿Cómo puedo copiar una imagen de un INPUT FILE a otro directorio?

Tags: java, html

Tengo una ruta PATH ejemplo:

```
C:\Users\ritchie\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Lavisa\build\web\upload\2.jpg
```

Y la quiero guardar en:

```
C:\Users\ritchie\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Lavisa\build\web\imagenes
```

¿Cómo puedo copiar esa imagen a otro directorio con `JAVA`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Ricardo es sencillo el guardar la imagen con la clase File

```
Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

source: es el origen

target: es el destino

REPLACE_EXISTING : es una opcion para remplazar los archivos en la carpeta destino si es que existen duplicados

fuente

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html